# How to get current position?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have been provided with this address and told to find the current location of me

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=address&output=csv
```

What kind of address is this and how can I get the information about this? Is  this API?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose if you give  http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=newyork&output=csv, the result will be 
200,4,40.7143528,-74.0059731.The last 2 values mean latitude and longitude value for New york...I hope it will help you.If you integrate this url in your app, you can get co-ordinates and use them to show the map in MKMapView in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

602,0,0,0

this is your location coordinates. and according to Google map you are located [image] here

Comment: How did you know where the OP is located? :)

Comment: no man at address position type ur address and in csv format write in which format u want the result like json etc.

Comment: OP = Original Poster = rajesh

Answer (score 0):

With that you can get latitude and longitude of an address. If you request this url and you use the address you want to find the coordinates you get 4 value as a response. You can use this function to get a Location object with lat and log of your address:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation:(NSString *)address {
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
  NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

  double latitude = 0.0;
  double longitude = 0.0;

  if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
  }
  else {
     //Show error
  }
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
  location.latitude = latitude;
  location.longitude = longitude;

  return location;
}
```

You can find more help here: http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

Comment: which is latitude and long in this json format   "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ -119.9590257, 36.2552300, 0 ]
    }

Comment: with this address http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Vanguard,CA,%20United%20States&output=json

Comment: anyway 36.2552300 is latitude and -119.9590257 is longitude. In gmaps: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=36.2552300,+-119.9590257&aq=&sll=36.244273,-119.94873&sspn=14.371852,24.345703&ie=UTF8&z=17